# How to identify the class of an Object which is in a cell of webtable

Tags: object, qtp

I have a webtable which MIGHT have a weblink object in it's Row 2, Column 1 cell (also Index of this object is 0). If it indeed is a link I would like to click it else ignore it. Is there a way to identify the class of this object given that we know the row and column number.

Below was my initial code. However it doesn't work always when the webtable cell doesn't have a link to click

```
Set Table = Browser("Oracle PeopleSoft").Page("Request Payment Predictor").WebTable("Run Control ID").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link", 0)
Table.Click
```

I would like to know if there a way to find the class of the Object (in cell of a web table) so I can click on the Object only if it's a link Or in other words can we use `GetRoProperty("Class Name")` on a WebTable Cell Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ChildItem` function returns a test object of the requested type if it exists, otherwise it returns `Nothing`.

So your code should look like this:

```
Set aLink = Browser("Oracle PeopleSoft")_
             .Page("Request Payment Predictor")_
               .WebTable("Run Control ID").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link", 0)

If Not aLink is Nothing Then
    aLink.Click
End If
```

The object returned by `ChildItem` is a test object (if it's not `Nothing`) so you can use the regular test object methods on it.

Please note that the object returned is not a *table cell* object, it's the object of the type you requested, this type may be `WebElement` which is considered the base class of all web objects. This means that you can use `ChildItem` with `"WebElement"` and then see what actual type it is by getting its [`micClass`](http://www.learnqtp.com/difference-between-class-classname-and-micclass-in-qtp/) (which is what the *Class Name* is called internally).

```
Print webElem.GetROProperty("micclass")
```

**Pro tip:** The indexes are 1 based, you can use the undocumented `Highlight` function in order to make sure you're working on the right object (`obj.Highlight`).

Comment: Thanks again Motti. You are the man.
This solves the problem I am facing. However I wasn't looking to  get the ROproperty of the Link Object in 2, 1 but was looking to set the (2, 1) cell as an object which necessarily might not be a link and then get the Classname of the object. Is that possible? Something like below

Set aObj = Browser("Oracle PeopleSoft")_
             .Page("Request Payment Predictor")_
               .WebTable("Run Control ID").<Childitem from (2,1) cell>
Classname_Obj = aObj.GetROProperty("Class Name")

Comment: Note: Your answer is indeed a solution as a work around. I was looking for a method to actually define the Cell as an Object without knowing what ObjectType we are dealing with. If that wouldnt be possible, I will mark your's as solution